# Hahn-Banach theorem implies functional hit 1

Tags: functional-analysis

> "By Hahn-Banach, there exists a nonzero bounded linear functional $f$ on $V$.  Then there exists $v_0 \in V$ with $f(v_0) \ne 0$; by rescaling we can get $f(v_0)=1$."

I don't understand why from Hahn-Banach's theorem we can infer this result. Hope everybody help please

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be any non-zero  element of $V$. Let $M=\{cv: c \in F\}$ where $F$ is the scalar field. Define $f(cv)=c$. This gives a bounded linear functional on $M$. By Hahn Banach Theorem it extends to a continuous linear functional on $V$ and we clearly have $f(v)=1$.

Comment: I still don't understand: "we clearly have $f(v)=1$." Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: The definition of $f$ on $M$ says $f(cv)=c$ for any scalar $c$. Just put $c=1$ to get $f(v)=1$. @tichtich

Comment: Thank you @Kavi Rama Murthy, you are so enthusiastic. This article is taken from the following problem: "If space of bounded operators L(V,W) is Banach, V nonzero, then W is Banach ". You think I have solved the problem just mentioned. Can you give me your solution for this problem for my reference

Comment: @tichtich Here si the basic idea: let $(w_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $W$. Define $T_n: V \to W$ by $T_n(x)=f(x) w_n$ where $f$ is the linear functional we have already constructed. It is now easy to see that $(T_n)$ is Cauchy in $L(V,W)$. If $T_n \to T$ then $w =\lim T(v)$ is an element of $W$ with $\|w_n-w\| \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy. The above solution I met but I always wonder if there is another more natural solution. I still find it hard to understand why we know how to choose $ f (v) = 1 $ and then define $ T_n (x) = f (x) w_n $. Do you know who was the first person to come up with a workaround and why they came up with this? And do you know of any other workarounds for this problem?